# i have 10 div(trigger) arrange horizontally,when hover on trigger element popup comes up but want to stay on popup content how do i do that?

Tags: jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        //If Javascript is running, change css on product-description to display:block
        //then hide the div, ready to animate
        $("div.pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})

        $("a.trigger").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).prev().stop().animate({
              opacity: 1
            }, 500);
          },
          function () {
            $(this).prev().stop().animate({
              opacity: 0
            }, 200);
          }
        )
      });
```

i have 10 div(trigger) arrange horizontally,when hover on trigger element popup comes up but want to stay on popup content how do i do that ?

Comment: see my original :http://jsfiddle.net/m2ku9/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little bit different solution here http://jsfiddle.net/9DD3v/

You can trigger the event by parent of link like `li`

html

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Show</a>
    <div class="profile">


    <div class="pop-up">
 <div style="margin-top:7px;position:absoult;left:0" ><font color=#f6f907 size=+1><b>Ii</b></font></div>nt.<br>Email :&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=mailto:d@nt.com>d@nt.com </a> <br>
Website :&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=http://www.nt.com>www.nt.com</a>
</div>
</li>
        <li>
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Show</a>
    <div class="profile">


    <div class="pop-up">
 <div style="margin-top:7px;position:absoult;left:0" ><font color=#f6f907 size=+1><b>Ii</b></font></div>nt.<br>Email :&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=mailto:d@nt.com>d@nt.com </a> <br>
Website :&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=http://www.nt.com>www.nt.com</a>
</div>
</li>
            </ul>
```

---

css

```
ul li {display:relative;float:left;margin-left:10px;}
div.profile{

    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-top: ;
    margin-left: ;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#222222 no-repeat; 
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 90%;
    border:none;
}
```

---

js

```
$(function(){
    $("li").hover(function(){
          $(this).children("div").stop().show(500);        
    },function(){
          $(this).children("div").stop().hide(500);            
    })
});
```

Comment: applaudable, thanks i will try it in production......& inform about it............i mean your solution fits me or not...... again thanks for your support......

Comment: IE 8 it work perfectly well but chrome 19.0 & fire fox no luck ?

Comment: its not working with chrome or firefox,100% sure.. would you please write down your complete css,html,javascript code over here,i will compare where i have gone wrong ,thanks for you time..........

Comment: Awesome,amazing,fabulous and fantastic you saved my costly time buddy thanks its working like a charm........hope i will not have problem with Safari browser too..........be connected.....for exchanging Knowledge.....regards

Answer (score 0):

take away the function thats sets the opacity to 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/m2ku9/

If thats wrong then try showing us your html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})

        var timer;
        $(".trigger, .pop-up").on({
            mouseenter : function () {
              clearTimeout(timer);
              $(this).prev().stop().animate({
                 opacity: 1
              }, 500);
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                var self = this;
                timer = setTimeout(function() {removeHover(self);}, 20);
            }
         });

         function removeHover(elm) {
             var element = $(elm).is('.pop-up') ? $(elm) : $(elm).prev();
             element.stop().animate({
                 opacity: 0
              }, 200);
         }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/shszE/)

Comment: yeah that true but i want horizontally div arranged see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ku9/11/

Comment: The principle remains the same, but your HTML markup is somewhat strange, missing quotes using inline styles and font tags, and if you write valid HTML the javascript function will work correctly.

Comment: @Yorgo - You're still doing strange things with your markup. Keep it simple, and you will end up with simple javascript functions. Restructured your HTML and moved all the styling you where trying to do with font tags, nbsp, breaks etc. into the css instead, and ended up with a really simple javascript solution. This is the way it's normally done if you write your HTML like normal people. Try to keep some sort of structure, it makes it so much easier when trying to figure something out later - See this : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/m2ku9/13/)

Comment: @adeneo these are not my HTML implementation. I just copy/paste asker code.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for your advise and totally agree with your words and suggestion and Fiddle out their...HTML Standards should be maintain as well CSS and Jscript or Javascript well said.......Thanks